# Is there any effective algorithm to find minimum-weight biconnected spanning subgraphs?

Tags: graph-theory, linear-programming

I would like to get one of the minimum-weight biconnected spanning subgraph of a graph. Is there any effective algorithm for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately this problem is NP-hard even for planar graphs. So there is no efficient solution if $\mathrm{P} \ne \mathrm{NP}$. But there are some weak [approximation schemes](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/fd65/5589012b90793dad2841a6936abe75374758.pdf) for this problem (it is called 2-VCSS). Good approximation schemes are known for either planar or unweighted cases.

EDIT. There is [$2$-approximation algorithm](http://libgen.io/book/index.php?md5=B172CE3F64E816612BA1971E0740CC21) (p. 115–129) for weighted version of generalized problem while there is [$\frac43$-approximation algorithm](http://libgen.io/book/index.php?md5=38F952E87FC9FAA407AC868301035B1D) (p. 262–273) for unweighted version.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please recommend a good approximation algorithm for unweighted cases?

Comment: @Roloka See links in the edited answer.